# Can not use '>' or '>>' to write to file from log.Println() and log.Printf()

Tags: unix, logging, go

I try to write to file using `>>` as usual by for Go project, It does not work.

`./main >> info.log` or `go run main.go >> info.log`

I'm running as root and I've tried to change file permission to 755 but still noting in info.log. I've also tried `ls >> ls.log` It works fine.
So I think there is something wrong with my code. All I use are `log.Println()` and `log.Printf()`

My code runs on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)

Comment: that's redirection. are you sure you have output in stdout?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go's [standard logger](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.4/src/log/log.go#L58) writes to stderr. You should either use `2>` and `2>>` and their friends in your shell scripts, or create your own logger that writes to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're writing to stdout, try using `fmt` instead of log. If the default `fmt.Println` and `fmt.Printf` don't work, the package details are here can get an io.Writer specific to stdout or stderr which will surely work. The docs are here https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/